# Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious to know why I'm getting this error? I've copied it exact from the website beezid.com (`carousel.js`) file, and I'm trying to get the same slide as them onto my website to update it.. As you can see I'm having issues with this?? Their site doesn't come up with this error?

> carousel.js:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined

```
Carousel = Class.create(Abstract, {
    initialize: function (scroller, slides, controls, options) {
        this.scrolling  = false;
        this.scroller   = $(scroller);
        this.slides     = slides;
        this.controls   = controls;
        this.menu       = false;
        this.menuTitleLen = 20;
```

Comment: The line that throws the error seems to not be in the code snippet. Could you post the whole thing?

Comment: If you are using Magento 1, your problem can be that the prototype library was loaded after your script trying to use the `Class.create`

Answer (score 9):

`Class` is not a JavaScript type, so you can't use it. That web site is probably using some third party library that provides a `Class` type to simplify some types creation etc.

From a quick inspection of the source code it is apparent that this site uses:

- [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) and
- [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/)

I think Prototype has a Class type. Here is a link to Prototype's tutorial on javascript "classes" and inheritance: http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance

Comment: Another lib providing Class [class.js](https://classjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js"></script>
```

You could use Prototype(http://prototypejs.org/) which is a library. Then the issue is resolved.